# How to lock function

Tags: go, mutex

```
var mutex sync.Mutex
func main() {
     handle()
    go register()
}

func register(){
   myObject.OnEvent().DoFunc(HandleConnect)
}
func HandleConnect(){
    handle()
}
func handle() bool {

    mutex = sync.Mutex{}
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    ....some logic.... do login...
    return true
}
```

I have a HandleConnect that is called many times in my application
I want to lock the handle because if there are many calls I want that only one will do the logic of the login
When I run it I got an error
**fatal error: sync: unlock of unlocked mutex**

How I can solve it ?

Comment: "unlock of unlocked mutex" means just what it says - something is calling `Unlock` on a mutex that isn't locked, which is not allowed. This isn't possible from the code shown, so it's being caused somewhere in the code that is not shown. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Also note that your code makes no sense as written, because the mutex is created inside the function where it's used. Thus each call to `handle` will be using its own mutex, and there will be no actual mutual exclusion.

Comment: This example is reassigning `mutex` every time `handle` is called, which sort of defeats the purpose of the mutex. Is that the actual code, and have to tried it with the race detector?

Comment: The other logic of this example do http call to login that it the most of the relevant code

Comment: I added more code that will look like my example with the logic

Comment: and the mutex is global so everyone that login to the function is locked , does it work like this ? so if I got many calls only the first one will do the hanlde the login logic and then the others will do the logic

Comment: i did the mutex as a global variable does it should work ?

Comment: @Adrian - why nd there will be no actual mutual exclusion , I want to lock it when it call to handle because there is logic to connect

Comment: It's a global variable, but it's being re-initialized every time you run handle(). Which is probably why you have an error... if you reinitialize it in one goroutine, then another tries to unlock it, you'll get the error you observe.

Comment: @Flimzy - how I can solve it ?

Comment: By not re-initializing the variable every time you run `handle()`.

Comment: @Flimzy - do I need to do it local variable ?

Comment: No. You just need to stop re-initializing it. That's it.

Comment: @Flimzy = sorry but what do you mean to re-initializing ? where I need to do the  mutex = sync.Mutex{} ?

Comment: You need to remove that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code. You're using a global variable (which is fine, as far as it goes), but then you're constantly resetting the mutex variable:

```
func handle() bool {
    mutex = sync.Mutex{} // Here you are re-initializing the mutex every time
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    ....some logic.... do login...
    return true
}
```

Instead, simply *don't* reset the variable:

```
func handle() bool {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    ....some logic.... do login...
    return true
}
```

To visualize the problem, imagine you have a single goroutine going through these steps:

1. Reset the mutex.  `mutex = sync.Mutex{}`
2. Lock the mutex.  `mutex.Lock()`
3. Do stuff `...some logic....`
4. Release the lock. `defer mutex.Unlock()`

All is fine.

But now imagine you have two groutines, **A** and **B** simultaneously running:

1. **A** resets the mutex: `mutex = sync.Mutex{}`
2. **A** locks the mutex: `mutex.Lock()`
3. **A** Do stuff
4. **B** resets the mutex: `mutex = sync.Mutex{}`  **NOTE:** The mutex is now unlocked for all goroutines, because it's a global variable!!
5. **A** Unlock mutex, and crash, because it's already unlocked